# Tomcat throwing "No suitable driver found" though I've already included the SQL drivers

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, jdbc

I have a script that queries data from SQL Server 2008. It works fine as a .java program.

When I implement this as a .jsp site I get the error

> HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:sqlserver://172.14.22.105;databaseName=mydbname;integratedSecurity=true

Though I included all of these libraries (which are what I use in the .java version):

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
```

and, following another Stack Overflow post on this error message, I downloaded `sqlserverjdbc.jar` and put it in `WEB-INF\lib`, then shut down Tomcat/Eclipse, restarted, and tried again.

Comment: I guess you might have the incorrect JAR. Visit http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2505, Click Download, open the downloaded html file, accept the agreement which should then download a ZIP file. Unzip it, and you should have a 'sqljdbc4.jar' which you should be able to use. Hope this helps.

Comment: @trishul Thanks. OK I downloaded the .exe and unzipped it, then copied `sqljdbc4.jar` to `WEB-INF\lib`. Stopped Tomcat and restarted it. Still getting the same error. Also just tried it again after `clean` and `clean Tomcat working directory`.

Comment: Note that embedding Java code directly into JSP pages (scriptlets) is highly discouraged in favor of clean MVC separation.

Comment: This seems to be strictly a configuration issue. Please post a GIT link to the codebase if possible or something else so that others can help as well.